# Backend list records TYPO3 extension

Tags: php, typo3, typo3-tca

I'm trying to create my first TYPO3 extension, with backend list records.

Now I can register my own list records, but they are registert under tt_news like this:

- News

  - News
  - News cat
  - Inventory

Of course I want to make my extension have it's own parent category like tt_news has.

- News

  - News
  - News cat
- Inventoy

  - inventory item

Does anybody have experience with this?

My ext_tables.php so far:

```
<?php
if (!defined ('TYPO3_MODE')) die ('Access denied.');

$TCA['tx_inventory_domain_model_product'] = array (
'ctrl' => array (
        'title' => 'Inventory',
        'label' => 'name',
),
'columns' => array(
        'name' => array(
        'label' => 'Item Label',
                'config' => array(
                        'type' => 'input',
                        'size' => '20',
                        'eval' => 'trim,required'
                )
        ),
        'description' => array(
                'label' => 'Item Description',
                'config' => array(
                        'type' => 'text',
                        'eval' => 'trim'
                )
        ),
        'quantity' => array(
                'label' => 'Stock Quantity',
                'config' => array(
                        'type' => 'input',
                        'size' => '4',
                        'eval'=> 'int'
                )
        ),
),
'types' => array(
        '0' => array('showitem' => 'name, description, quantity')
)
);
?>
```

Comment: It's being added under News rather accidently (if you installed some other extension, it might appear under it instead) than because of some setting. You are surely missing some things. Have you created this extension with the **kickstarter** extension? If not, I suggest you start with that as it will create for you all the files with all the necessary directives in them. It will give you an idea of what's needed and you won't need the kickstarter when writing your second extension.

Comment: I've not been using kickstarter indeed, so ill try that. Ill let you know

Comment: What TYPO3 version? It might be a bug in 4.5.

Comment: @jvermolen Did it work out for you?

Comment: Ive used kickstarter and that worked